# The repository 'xyz' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

I'm not experienced enough with operation systems and I have a common issue that I looked for a solution but no one is valid.

when I run `sudo apt update`, I get the following error:

[image: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.]

When I tried to install certbot (http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu) in my Ubuntu 20.04, I added a repository so I can download it, but later the OS tell me that "Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default"

I don't remember how I added it, but it's clearly the solution is remove it from that "package lists". I spent hours looking for a solution but none is valid, why is no one did a clear explanation on how to add/remove a repository from "package lists" ?

can anyone write a valid answer so anyone have this issue will directly find a valid solution for different repositories ?

Comment: Disco (Ubuntu 19.04) was the last time that repo was supported:  http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: Since this question is closed, the answer was explained in depth here: https://askubuntu.com/a/92897/1639701.